# The rm -f command in my Makefile is not working

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Referring to the code below, the command `rm -f *.o` is not removing the `realnumsets.o` and `gestore.o` files after the compile process. Do you have any suggestions for how I can remove these `*.o` files?

```
~/workspace$ more Makefile
eseguibile : gestore.o realnumsets.o Makefile
        gcc -ansi -Wall -O gestore.o realnumsets.o -o myprog

gestore.o : gestore.c realnumsets.h Makefile
        gcc -ansi -Wall -O -c gestore.c

realnumsets.o : realnumsets.c realnumsets.h Makefile
        gcc -ansi -Wall -O -c realnumsets.c

clean :
        rm -f *.o
```

```
~/workspace$ make 
gcc -ansi -Wall -O -c gestore.c
gcc -ansi -Wall -O -c realnumsets.c
gcc -ansi -Wall -O gestore.o realnumsets.o -o myprog
```

```
~/workspace$ ls -la
total 60
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 May 20 17:57 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 May 20 14:33 ../
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   289 May 20 16:35 Makefile
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  6271 May 20 14:45 gestore.c
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  4624 May 20 17:57 gestore.o
-rwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 13588 May 20 17:57 myprog*
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  5101 May 20 14:44 realnumsets.c
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   584 May 20 14:08 realnumsets.h
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  3792 May 20 17:57 realnumsets.o
```

Expected results:

```
~/workspace$ ls 
Makefile  gestore.c  myprog*  realnumsets.c  realnumsets.h
```

Actual result:

```
~/workspace$ ls 
Makefile  gestore.c  gestore.o  myprog*  realnumsets.c  realnumsets.h  realnumsets.o
```

Comment: To state the obvious, you only run `make` which invokes the default recipe. You never run `make clean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The make utility works toward a specific target when it is run. If you specify a target, that will be the one make works toward. By default, the first target (not starting with a period) will be made if you don't specify a target. Thus your simple invocation with just

```
make
```

will start work on the target eseguibile. Make pulls in the targets gestore.o and realnumsets.o as those are needed to create eseguibile. The clean target isn't needed for eseguibile, so it doesn't run.

In theory, you could add your clean target to end of the list of targets in eseguibile. However, this would be an unusual way of doing things. More commonly, you just separately call:

```
make clean
```

after you run make for the build. If you want to clean before a build is done you could accomplish this with:

```
make clean eseguibile
```

The clean will be done first, so you would start building new .o files.

Answer (score 6):

You have to run `make clean` to run the clean target. Typing just `make` runs only the default target (`eseguibile`) and its dependencies.